# Как создать кнопку поделиться?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, share

Как создать кнопку поделиться?

Например в каком то сайте нажимаешь поделиться и расплывается окошко где можно выбрать где паделисьтя.
Например есть несколько вариантов Facebook,Tvitter, Instagram и почта.
Если нажмешь на facebook то открывается акошка где можно написать статью в Facebook

P.S. Простите если тупо объяснил

Comment: Уже готовых решений огромное количество. Например, вот https://codepen.io/vabhishek-me/pen/LNxdVX

Answer (score 0):

некогда не делал но по идее(чисто теоритически) => добавляеш кнопку => после клика модалка с F,T,I после выбора => модалка с вводом информации => подключаеш апишку F-api,T-api,I-api и по нему отправляеш данные